# Access root path on member block

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I've got the following route block, and want to add the `GET` handler for `charges/:id`.

```
resources :charges, only: [:index, :create] do
  member do
    post :capture
  end
end
```

I've tried adding `root :index` to the `member` block but that didn't work..

Comment: Do you mean a show method? like resources :charges, only: [:show, :index, :create] do .....

Comment: I want a GET handler for an individual `charge` with an `:id`

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions
As you can see here, :show method gives you a GET request

Comment: Thanks! can you put in an answer with the full solution so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying here is the show action mentioned here:

guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Try this in routes.rb:

```
resources :charges, only: [:show, :index, :create] do
  member do
    post :capture
  end
end
```

Comment: Didn't realize that the `:show` method actually operated on the `member`s.. Thanks for the link to the docs!